# The <label> with long text in horizontal-form doesn't center vertically opposite input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new user of Twitter Bootstrap.

I have a form, this form has a label with very long text inside (all text can't be placed to only one row, and therefore my label occupy more than one row). Here is the markup:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="doc_acq" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-muted">Very very very very very very very very very long label name here</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input field="mandatory_field" type="text" class="form-control" name="doc_acq" id="doc_acq"></input>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is how it looks in my browser:

[image]

As you can see, label isn't centered opposite input field. How can I center it?

Comment: You shouldn't post code as an image if it can be just as easily posted as code. This will enable answerers to just copy the code and try it out. To make it even easier for others to answer, you should provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: If the label is that long it maybe a good idea to use (placeholder) to display the text inside the input box -- http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: yeah, I know about placeholder, but it isn't acceptable for my form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some edit to your html and added a css class
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hQc9f/1/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1 vcenter">
        <label for="doc_acq" class="control-label text-muted">Very very very very very very very very very long label name here</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10 vcenter">
       <input field="mandatory_field" type="text" class="form-control" name="doc_acq" id="doc_acq"/>

    </div>   

</div>
```

added this css class

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

in this way input field is always vertically centered with label

Comment: thanks, I have tried before similar css but without div wrapper for my lable :-)